# Python : Strange multiprocessing function crash in console

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, multiprocessing, anaconda, virtualenv

I maintain an experimental tool that still python 2.7 that use a bunch of libraries, such as Gdal, shapely, astropy, OpenCV2, scipy, etc. Everything was fine until the system as changed, so virtual environment has been redone and then I have a problem with multiprocessing function.

**The most simplified code to reproduce the behaviour:**

```
import multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    cpus = cpus - 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus)
```

**Result #1 with:**

- Python : VirEnv 2.7 build
- Console : Pycharm PyDev console

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1,
>   in    File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line
>   380, in main
>       prepare(preparation_data)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 504, in prepare
>   File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
>       file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs) ImportError: No module named input
>       prepare(preparation_data)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 504, in prepare
>       file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs) ImportError: No module named input

Why it is looking into "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\" instead of the VirEnv 2.7 build?

**Result #2 with:**

- Python : VirEnv 2.7 from Anaconda
- Console : Pycharm PyDev console

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Python_27\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py",
>   line 105, in spawn_main
>       exitcode = _main(fd)   File "C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Python_27\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py",
>   line 114, in _main
>       prepare(preparation_data)   File "C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Python_27\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py",
>   line 225, in prepare
>       _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])   File "C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Python_27\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py",
>   line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
>       run_name="**mp_main**")   File "C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Python_27\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 261, in run_path
>       code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)   File "C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Python_27\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 231, in _get_code_from_file
>       with open(fname, "rb") as f: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\'

**Result #3 with:**

- Python : VirEnv 2.7 build
- Console : Pycharm terminal

Passed without error

**Result #4 with:**

- Python : VirEnv 2.7 from Anaconda
- Console : Pycharm terminal

Passed without error

**Result #5 with:**

- Python : VirEnv 2.7 from Anaconda
- Console : Anaconda terminal

Passed without error

So, Pycharm PyDev console seems where only the crash occurs? Why? How to get rid of this?

**In addition** :

After the console initialization, I have:

```
B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=_____
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['B:\\WorkingSpace\\_____\\API', 'B:/WorkingSpace/_____/API'])
PyDev console: starting.
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

When I pass the simplified code to reproduce the behaviour, the error "ImportError: No module named " occur in the forking.py which is in the path "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\".

Sys.path are:

- 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
  2019.2\helpers\pydev',
- 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\third_party\thriftpy',
- 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition   2019.2\helpers\pydev',
- 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python27.zip',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7\DLLs',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7\lib',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7\lib\plat-win',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7\lib\lib-tk',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7\Scripts',
- 'C:\Python27\Lib',
- 'C:\Python27\DLLs',
- 'C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API\virEnv_Desktop_V2.7\lib\site-packages',
- 'B:\WorkingSpace\_____\API',
- 'B:/WorkingSpace/_____/API'

What happening?

Comment: Even more strange... If I launch test.py that contain the simplified code. It's fine! It's seems to be strictly related the "Python Dev Console of Pycharm"...

Comment: Please check that the project is configured to work with the virtual environment, and not the global interpreter

Comment: @AvivBar-el Project Interpreter were pointing the VirEnv 2.7 build or VirEnv 2.7 from Anaconda.